# qTip not showing on dynamically added elements by other javascript code

Tags: javascript, jquery, qtip, qtip2

This is my qTip settings:

```
<script>

    $(document).ready( function () {

        $('.hasTooltip').each(function() {
            $(this).qtip({
                content: {
                    text: $(this).next('div').html()
                },
                position: {
                    my: 'bottom center', 
                    at: 'top center',
                    target: $(this)
                },
                show: {
                    event: 'click mouseenter',
                    solo: true,
                    effect: function(offset) {
                        $(this).fadeIn(100);
                    }
                },
                hide: {
                    fixed: true,
                    delay: 300
                }
            });
        });

        show_registration_form(); // add HTML form with qTip tootlip elements

        function show_registration_form() {

            $(".content-area").append('<form action="" method="POST"></form>');

            var form2Html = [

                '<input type="text" value="" name="username" id="username">',
                '<input type="email" value="" name="email" id="email">',

                // ... standard form content

            ].join('');

            $(".content-area form").append(form2Html);

        }

    });

</script>
```

And this is my html added via a function that is called from my custom js code:

```
<div class="hasTooltip">Hover me to see a tooltip</div>
<div class="hidden">This is just a test! <a href="http://google.com">Link test</a></div>
```

How to make qTip work on dynamically added elements too?

**UPDATE:**

I have added more code and comments including the function that adds HTML elements that contains qTip tooltips dynamically.

Comment: What code dynamically adds the elements? Run this after that code.

Comment: @RGraham I have updated my code, please, check now.

Comment: Just move `show_registration_form` above the `$(".hasToolip").each`. Essentially, you need to call `qtip` each time you add a new element

Comment: @RGraham Thanks, I put tthe code with tooltip before `</body>` tag to prevent moving the code in the future and it's working now. However, how to do it to be independent on the position in code. Is it possible? Could `bind` or `live` be used? If yes, how?

Comment: Possibly. `on` (replacement for deprecated `live`) only happens on an event, so you would need to trigger it on an element. Unfortunately there is no `loaded` event for DOM elements

Comment: Have a look at triggering custom events: http://api.jquery.com/trigger/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to execute the $().qtip(); on every element you dynamically add after they've been added.

At the moment, you add the qTips right after the page is ready, then add the new elements and then nothing.

I haven't tested this, might need tweaking, but try this code, this tries to add the tooltip to the dynamically added username and email input fields:

```
$(document).ready( function () {
  $('.hasTooltip').each(function() {
        qTipAdd(this);
  });

  show_registration_form(); // add html form with elements from my custom js function

});

function show_registration_form() {
    $(".content-area").append('<form action="" method="POST"></form>');

    var form2Html = [

        '<input type="text" value="" name="username" id="username">',
        '<input type="email" value="" name="email" id="email">',

        // ... standard form content
    ].join('');

    $(".content-area form").append(form2Html);

    qTipAdd('#username');
    qTipAdd('#email');
}

function qTipAdd(element) {
    $(element).qtip({
        content: {
            text: $(this).next('div').html()
        },
        position: {
            my: 'bottom center', 
            at: 'top center',
            target: $(this)
        },
        show: {
            event: 'click mouseenter',
            solo: true,
            effect: function(offset) {
                $(this).fadeIn(100);
            }
        },
        hide: {
            fixed: true,
            delay: 300
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Could you show my where in my current code should I place `$().qtip();` ? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can bind event by document, and initialize qtip on the first time event triggered:

```
$(document).on('click', '.dynamic-element-class', function(){
   // return if qtip already initialized
   if( 'object' === typeof $(elem).data('qtip') ) return
   $(element).qtip({
      content: {
        text: $(this).next('div').html()
      },
      position: {
        my: 'bottom center', 
        at: 'top center',
        target: $(this)
      },
      show: {
        ready: true, // Show qtip on initialization 
        event: 'click mouseenter',
        solo: true,
        effect: function(offset) {
            $(this).fadeIn(100);
        }
      },
      hide: {
        fixed: true,
        delay: 300
      }
  });
})
```